# Point not a valid property - MongoDB & Grails 3.3+

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, geospatial, geo

Having a really weird issue in Grails and MongoDB where in my production environment I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property [location] is not a valid property of class [domain].Tracking
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.FieldEntityAccess$FieldEntityReflector.getPropertyReader(FieldEntityAccess.java:268)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.FieldEntityAccess$FieldEntityReflector.getProperty(FieldEntityAccess.java:286)
        at grails.gorm.validation.PersistentEntityValidator.validatePropertyWithConstraint(PersistentEntityValidator.groovy:319)
        at grails.gorm.validation.PersistentEntityValidator.validate(PersistentEntityValidator.groovy:76)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidationApi.doValidate(GormValidationApi.groovy:124)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidationApi.validate(GormValidationApi.groovy:153)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidateable$Trait$Helper.validate(GormValidateable.groovy:71)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidateable$Trait$Helper$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at [domain].Tracking.validate(Tracking.groovy)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.doSave(GormInstanceApi.groovy:332)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.doSave(GormInstanceApi.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:947)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:930)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:92)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi$_save_closure5.doCall(GormInstanceApi.groovy:179)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.doInSession(Unknown Source)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:40)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save(GormInstanceApi.groovy:178)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at [domain].Tracking.save(Tracking.groovy)
        at [domain].Tracking.save(Tracking.groovy)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
        at autovision.web.BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:139)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1099)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:541)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:534)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:510)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:74)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:261)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at autovision.web.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

This is happening when I try to insert a new Tracking Object into the DB like so :

```
  Tracking tp = new Tracking()
  tp.setUser(user)
  nowCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,i++)
  tp.setCreated(nowCal.getTime())
  tp.setSpeed(10f)
  tp.setLocation(new Point(points[1],points[0]))
  tp.save(flush:true)

  user.addToTracking(tp);
```

And my Tracking class is defined as so :

```
import grails.mongodb.geo.Point

class Tracking {

    Point location

    Date created

    float speed

    static belongsTo = [user:User]

    static constraints = {
        speed nullable:true
    }

    static mapping = {
        location geoIndex:'2dsphere'
    }
}
```

I really can't see what the problem is here, I Think I've defined everything correctly as it shows in the GORM documentation : http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/#geoSpatial

The other thing is this code works perfectly well when running in non prod mode.

so executing `grails run-app` works but `grails prod run-app` doesn't..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Lee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and after two days of debugging finally found a workaround.

#### The problem was caused by the following:

- There is a Grails utility class called `org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.FieldEntityAccess`, apparently used to access entities fields using reflection. That class has an inner class called `FieldEntityReflector`. Every time a `FieldEntityAccess` instance is created, there is an instance of `FieldEntityReflector` created internally. All those instances are stored in a static map called `REFLECTORS`, whose keys are the entity names, apparently for performance reasons.
- During bean initialization, `mongoDatastore` bean creates one `FieldEntityAccess` for each entity, passing a `DocumentPersistentEntity` as constructor parameter.
- In the same way, `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` bean, unaware of `mongoDatastore` creates its own `FieldEntityAccess` for each entity, passing down `KeyValuePersistentEntity` as parameter. Those `FieldEntityAccess` instances and their corresponding `EntityReflectors` are unaware of mongo and therefore don't support mongo specific types like `Point`.
- Given that the `REFLECTORS` map keys are entity names, `EntityReflectors` created last for the same entity, override previously created reflectors, and are used by all `EntityReflector` instances.
- When `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` reflectors are created last, they are used when mongo tries to persist and entity and therefore throw an error.

#### In short, the error is thrown when `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` bean is initialized after `mongoDatastore` bean.

In development mode, `UrlMappingsGrailsPlugin` plugin creates some beans used to allow url mappings reloading. Those beans trigger instantiation of `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` bean before `mongoDatastore` bean. As the mongo beans are created later, the error is not thrown. But, in production mode, those beans are not created, and `mongoDatastore` is created before `grailsDomainClassMappingContext`, therefore throwing the error.

#### Potential solutions

1. **Force `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` bean instantiation before `mongoDatastore`:** I was unable to do that after several attempts, maybe because of grails bean instantiation logic.
2. **Force `UrlMappingsGrailsPlugin` instantiation even on production mode:** I prefered not to go that way due to possible permformance implications.
3. **Use the static method `clearReflectors` of `FieldEntityAccess` class** to clear all the reflectors after system initialization:** I decided to do that and the system started to work. I haven't tested it in depth, but was able to persist `Point` correctly.

In order to call the method, I created a bean depending on both `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` and `mongoDatastore` and called `FieldEntityAccess.clearReflectors()`

```
package app.utils

import org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.FieldEntityAccess
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.MappingContext

class MongoDatastoreHolder {

    MongoDatastore mongo

    MappingContext context

    MongoDatastoreHolder(MappingContext context, MongoDatastore mongo) {
        this.context = context
        this.mongo = mongo
        FieldEntityAccess.clearReflectors()
    }
}
```

And defined that bean in `resources.groovy`:

```
import app.utils.MongoDatastoreHolder

beans = {
    mongoDatastoreHolder(MongoDatastoreHolder, ref('grailsDomainClassMappingContext'), ref('mongoDatastore')) { bean ->
        bean.lazyInit = false
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, and sorry for my bad english, this is my first StackOverflow answer.